# How to list images and tags from the gcr.io Docker Registry using the HTTP API?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-registry, google-container-registry

I'm trying to fetch a list of available images and their tags from Google Container Registry (gcr.io) in Node.js.

I first use `google-auto-auth` to optain a token with scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`,
and I exchange that token for a `gcr.io` token like so:

```
axios.get('https://gcr.io/v2/token?service=gcr.io', {
  auth: {
    username: '_token',
    password: token // token I got from `google-auto-auth`
  }
})
```

I then try to use this to call the `v2/_catalog` endpoint:

```
axios.get('https://gcr.io/v2/_catalog', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${gcrToken}`
  }
})
```

And I get the following error:

```
{ 
  errors: [ { code: 'DENIED', message: 'Failed to retrieve projects.' } ] 
}
```

Fair enough, it must require my project ID, but where am I supposed to provide it?

Just to see if I could get anything else working, I tried:

```
axios.get('https://gcr.io/v2/my-project-id/my-image/tags/list', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${gcrToken}`
  }
})
```

And I get the following back:

```
{ 
  errors: [ 
    { 
      code: 'NAME_INVALID', 
      message: 'Requested repository does not match bearer token resource: my-project-id/my-image' 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

How can I read image info from gcr.io?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After extensive communication with Jon Johnson from GCR, we finally figured out what was wrong. If you upvote this answer, please upvote Jon's as well, he went above and beyond to get this issue resolved.

Most of this stuff is undocumented as of this writing.

- need to use the `registry:catalog:*` scope.
- my images were pushed to `us.gcr.io`, and they treat them as separate registries — I thought they were mirrors.
- the service account must have the `Project Viewer` role in Google Cloud IAM.
- you can use a GCR token, as well as a Google Cloud token. However while the GCR token cannot be used with `Basic base64(_token:<token>)`, the Google Cloud token can.

**Getting the GCR token**

```
// Updated host
axios.get('https://us.gcr.io/v2/token?service=gcr.io', {
  params: {
    service: 'us.gcr.io',
    scope: `registry:catalog:*`
  },
  auth: {
    username: '_token',
    password: token // token I got from `google-auto-auth`
  },  
})
```

**Using the token to list repositories**

```
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://us.gcr.io/v2`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }
})

client.get('/_catalog').then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data.repositories)
})
```

Comment: It works for me even if I assign role _roles/browser_ rather than _roles/viewer_ to the service account. It's a "weaker" role so might be a safer choice from security perspective.

Comment: You also have to enable the Cloud Resource Manager API (cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com) in your project containing the docker images, otherwise you will be met with a 403.

Answer (score 8):

The first error is likely because you're missing one of the scopes for listing projects:
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list#authorization

You get the second error because you're missing the scope in your token exchange.

You want something like:

```
https://gcr.io/v2/token?service=gcr.io&scope=repository:<my-project-id/my-image>:*
```

See the example here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/#requesting-a-token

Comment: I tried adding `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly` as a scope, same error.

Comment: That's unexpected. Please feel free to reach out to us at gcr-contact@google.com and we can help you debug this further.