# how to obtain GCR access token with python / listing docker images

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

The access token im getting with `gcloud auth print-access-token` is obviously a different access token than the one i can get with some basic python code:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/the-credentials.json
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
credentials.get_access_token()
```

What i am trying to do is get a token that would work with:

```
curl -u _token:<mytoken> https://eu.gcr.io/v2/my-project/my-docker-image/tags/list
```

I'd prefer not to install gcloud utility as a dependency for my app, hence my tries to obtain the access token progrmatically via oath google credentials

Comment: I've got essentially the same question - Do we _really_ need to install the humongous gcloud utility just to facilitate this token step? Surely there is another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a very old question, but I just got faced with [the exact same problem of requiring an ACCESS_TOKEN in Python and not being able to generate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59795798/how-to-turn-on-off-cloudsql-instances-using-python3/59828404#59828404), and managed to make it work.

What you need to do is to use the variable `credentials.token`, except it won't exist once you first create the credentials object, returning `None`. In order to generate a token, the credentials must be used by a google.cloud library, which in my case was done by using the `googleapiclient.discovery.build` method:

```
sqladmin = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4', credentials=credentials)
response = sqladmin.instances().get(project=PROJECT_ID, instance=INSTANCE_ID).execute()
print(json.dumps(response))
```

After which the ACCESS_TOKEN could be properly generated using

```
access_token = credentials.token
```

I've also tested it using `google.cloud storage` as a way to test credentials, and it also worked, by just trying to access a bucket in GCS through the appropriate Python library:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage
PROJECT_ID = your_project_id_here
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
try:
    list(storage.Client(project=PROJECT_ID, credentials=credentials).bucket('random_bucket').list_blobs())
except:
    print("Failed because no bucket exists named 'random_bucket' in your project... but that doesn't matter, what matters is that the library tried to use the credentials and in doing so generated an access_token, which is what we're interested in right now")

access_token = credentials.token
print(access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think there are a few questions:

**`gcloud auth print-access-token` vs GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()**

`gcloud` doesn't set application default credentials by default anymore when performing a `gcloud auth login`, so the access_token you're getting from `gcloud auth print-access-token` is going to be the one corresponding to the used you used to login.

As long as you follow the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) to create ADC's for a service account, that account has [the necessary permissions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/troubleshooting#permission_issues_when_communicating_with_google_product_name), and the environment from which you are executing the script has access to the ENV var and the adc.json file, you should be fine.

**How to make `curl` work**

The Docker Registry API specifies that a token exchange should happen, swapping your Basic auth (i.e. `Authorization: Basic base64(_token:<gcloud_access_token>)`) for a short-lived Bearer token. This process can be a bit involved, but is documented [here under "How to authenticate" and "Requesting a Token"](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/auth/token.md#how-to-authenticate). Replace `auth.docker.io/token` with `eu.gcr.io/v2/token` and `service=registry.docker.io` with `service=eu.gcr.io`, etc. Use `curl -u oauth2accesstoken:<mytoken>` here.

See also: [How to list images and tags from the gcr.io Docker Registry using the HTTP API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783736/how-to-list-images-and-tags-from-the-gcr-io-docker-registry-using-the-http-api)

**Avoid the question entirely**

We have a python lib that might be relevant to your needs:
https://github.com/google/containerregistry

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i am not finding this response very useful. Part 1 explains sth that i followed and had no problem with.

Part two admits that process can be involved and specifies that there is a solution if i do a series of replaces and some queries.

Finally, you reference a "lib" that is not documented at all. No description, no use cases, nothing. Just "read-the-code-if-you-want-to-know-what-it-does".

Id press -1 on this, but im too low rep :(