# How to authorize to GCR using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authorization, google-container-registry

I'm trying to use Docker registry V2 API with Google Container Registry, specifically this endpoint:

```
curl -I \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  https://gcr.io/v2/$PROJECT/hello/blobs/$digest
```

But I'd like to do it with code and not via CLI and not using `gcloud`.
I have a service account and a json key file. Is it possible?

This is a related question [Get service account auth token without gcloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059976/get-service-account-auth-token-without-gcloud)
But the link attached in the chosen answer doesn't help with this need.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is documented here [1]. It explains how to authorize requests with a service account using Node.Js.

Here is also how to provide credentials to the application (also using NodeJS)[2].

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/nodejs-guide#authorization

[2] https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application

Answer (score 0):

The following code works (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783736/how-to-list-images-and-tags-from-the-gcr-io-docker-registry-using-the-http-api)), using [google-auto-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auto-auth). Note that you might need to define [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) in your environment:

```
const googleAuth = require('google-auto-auth');

const authConfig = {scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write']};

// Create a client
const auth = googleAuth(authConfig);

auth.getToken(function (err, token) {
  if (err)
      console.log(err);
  else { 
     //  Send a request to the relevant Docker Registry V2 API endpoint
     //  with header `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`
  }

});
```